# How to work on python with postgresql on Heroku?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, telegram

I am writing a bot for telegrams. First, I used sqlite, but then I realized that Heroku does not support sqlite and chose postgresql. I found postgresql already in heroku. But I do not know how to work with it. Can eat some step-by-step articles or something else?

I will be very thankful.